# Google Chrome For i686

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu-14.04, apt-get

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS from 12.04 LTS, and I am trying to install google-chrome.

I write:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_i686.deb
```

And it returns:

```
--2016-08-29 10:53:16--  https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_i686.deb
Resolving dl.google.com (dl.google.com)... 74.125.192.91, 74.125.192.190, 74.125.192.136, ...
Connecting to dl.google.com (dl.google.com)|74.125.192.91|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2016-08-29 10:53:17 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Same thing with:

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=i686] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package google-chrome-stable is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'google-chrome-stable' has no installation candidate
```

Is there a google-chrome for my architecture?

For info:

```
uname -a
Linux Elmwood 3.13.0-93-generic #140-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jul 18 21:20:08 UTC 2016 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chrome [dropped support](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-dev/FoE6sL-p6oU) for x86 and i686.

You'll have to either use an old version of Chrome or move to x86_64 if you want to use a Debian package. You may also be able to compile Chromium yourself for your architecture, but you'll need to do that for every release.

Comment: Well that sucks. I just built Chromium. Thanks.